# Compare values within list of rows in R

Tags: r

I've identified a list of row numbers in a large data frame using the following:

```
brownturkey_rows <- grep("brown",Dataframe$color)
```

For which I get

```
brownturkey_rows int [1:5] 3 6 7 8 9
```

Now I need to check a certain condition in each of those rows and return which rows fail. For example looking at row 6:

```
Dataframe$age[6] < Dataframe$limit[6]
```

In perl, I would have used a foreach loop. What is the best way to do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
subset(Dataframe[grep("brown", Dataframe$color),], age < limit)
```

That is, you use the output of the `grep` as a filter on `Dataframe`,
and then you further filter the results using `subset`.

As [@moody-mudskipper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270475/moody-mudskipper) pointed out, an even better way:

```
subset(Dataframe, grepl("brown", color) & age < limit)
```

Here `grepl` is used to get logical values of the filtering instead of the values themselves,
and combine that directly with the other logical condition that you're interested in (`age < limit`).

Another way:

```
d2 <- Dataframe[grep("brown", Dataframe$color),]
d2[with(d2, age < limit),]
```

Comment: That's not a very consistent use of subset, I'd do `subset(Dataframe, grepl("brown",color) & age < limit)`

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't even think of using a subset, and the fact that you can combine it into one simple line is great. Every time I learn something new in R, my mind is blown with how powerful it is. Thanks!!